# javascript URL.createObjectURL return is not image URL in ie

Tags: javascript, image, file, parsing, preview

i will make file upload image preview system
i use URL.createObjectURL method
this method return type is 'blob:http://~~' in chrome
but ie return is 'blob:AB0CC6B1-~~'
so i can't parse input images

```
function onFileAllChanged(event){
    var sizeArray=document.getElementById('fileAllUploadButton').files;
    if(sizeArray.length==0){
        return;
    }else if(sizeArray.length>5){
        alert('사진은 최대 5장까지 입니다.')
        return;
    }
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
        var sizeImage = new Image();
        sizeImage.onload = function(){
            var width = this.width;
            var height = this.height;
            if(3000<width||3000<height){
                alert("이미지의 사이즈나 용량이 너무 큽니다.")
                while(fileList.length!=0){
                    fileList.pop();
                }
                for(var resetIndex=0;resetIndex<5;resetIndex++){
                    $('.subImage .subImageControllerBox:eq(' + resetIndex + ')').css('background-image', 'none');
                    $('.subImage .subImageControllerBox:eq(' + resetIndex + ')').attr('image-path','none');
                    $('.subImage .subImageControllerBox:eq(' + resetIndex + ')').attr('image-filter','none');
                }
                return;
            }
        };
        var path = window.URL.createObjectURL(sizeArray[i]);
        console.log('temp:'+path);
        sizeImage.src=path;
    }
    var getFormFile = document.getElementById('fileAllUploadButton').files;
    while(fileList.length!=0){
       fileList.pop();
    }
    for(var k=0;k<getFormFile.length;k++){
       fileList.push(getFormFile[k]);
    }
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
        var path = URL.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
        if(i==0){
            viewScreenImages(path,"default",i);
        }
        if(fileList[i]!=undefined) {
            $('.subImage .subImageControllerBox:eq(' + i + ')').css('background-image', 'url(' + path + ')');
            $('.subImage .subImageControllerBox:eq(' + i + ')').attr('image-path',path);
            $('.subImage .subImageControllerBox:eq(' + i + ')').attr('image-filter','default');
        }else{
            $('.subImage .subImageControllerBox:eq(' + i + ')').css('background-image', 'none');
            $('.subImage .subImageControllerBox:eq(' + i + ')').attr('image-path','none');
            $('.subImage .subImageControllerBox:eq(' + i + ')').attr('image-filter','none');
        }
    }
}
```

how to fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to parse?

Comment: user uploaded image from '<input type='file'>' in current page

Comment: i reference this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploade

Comment: but i use html5 canvas so create Image object

Comment: I see you've loaded the image in, but I don't think anyone understands what information you're trying to get from the image? P.S MDN: "Each of these must be released by calling URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL) when you no longer need them." - you should revoke in the `onload` callback.